# How do I ignore unmet dependencies while using apt-get remove?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, dependencies

I have a thin VPS running Ubuntu 14.04 with automatic security updates. It has filled up the /boot partition with a lot of kernel updates. I am trying to remove the older ones, but I'm running into an "unmet" dependencies error demanding I fix another package before I can continue. Unfortunately, the unmet dependency wants to install a new kernel to the partition that is 100% full.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove [an old linux-image* package]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-88-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-88-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-88-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

With the partition full, there is no way I can `apt-get -f install` to correct anything. Is there a way to tell `apt-get` to not check for unmet dependencies in the database, which have nothing to do with the packages I need to remove? Once I free up some space, I can actually solve the broken packages too.

My alternate solution is to manually free up space by moving some kernels out of the way (to `/kernels`), fix the dependency issue, remove some kernel packages, and move `/kernels/*` back if I cannot instruct `apt-get` to cooperate otherwise.

**EDIT**

I tried `apt-get -f remove PACKAGENAME`, but it hit the dep error. But `apt-get -f autoremove` ignored the dep problems. Without -f, autoremove hit the dep error. With it, some kernels were found for removal and it is working on it. So while my immediate problem is resolved, I still would like to know if the regular `apt-get -f remove PACKAGENAME` can have the same capability of ignoring unrelated dependency issues.

Comment: for future reference had you executed following command every few days you would be fine now ...   DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive sudo apt-get update &&  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive  sudo apt-get -f install -y && sudo env DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confnew" -yy dist-upgrade -yq && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive sudo apt-get autoremove -yq && sudo apt-get autoclean -y &&  [ -f /var/run/reboot-required ] && sudo reboot now

Comment: also be aware current ubuntu auto cleans up its boot partition unlike old releases

Answer (score 5):

`dpkg --remove` DOES remove the packages without complaining about the failed install. That get you disk space to do `apt-get -f autoremove`

Comment: (not original poster) the problem is you cannot do anything with apt-get until these dependencies are resolved.

Comment: it complains on dependencies instead...